# Express mapping from $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ as a function $f: \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

Express $\underline{f}(x,y)=(4x^2,y^2)$ as a function $f: \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$.

How do I go about this? I think it's something like $4x^2+y^2i$ but obviously there should only be one variable so how do I deal with that?

Also how would I do the reverse and express $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-i}$ from $\mathbb C \setminus\{i\} \to \mathbb C$ as a mapping $\underline{f}:\mathbb R^2\setminus\{(0,1)\}\to \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Why is it obvious that there should only be one variable?

Comment: I thought that because my function had to be from $\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ rather than $\mathbb C^n \to \mathbb C^n$ where $n$ is an integer greater than 1 that there should be 1 variable rather than $n$. Is this right?

Comment: It's not right. You need to find a map $\overline f\colon \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ that corresponds to $f$ in some way. You already did that.

Comment: Oh ok, so the answer is $f(x,y)=4x^2+y^2i$? I just didn't think it could be so trivial

Comment: Depending exactly on how you're defining $\mathbb C$, it might be better to write $f(x+iy)=4x^2+y^2i$, but yes, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Trivial answer for the first part:
$$f(z)=4\Re(z)^2+\Im(z)^2i.$$
For the second part:
$$
\frac1{z-i}=\frac{\bar{z}+i}{(z-i){(\bar{z}+i)}}=\frac{\bar z+i}{|z-i|^2}=\frac{x-iy+i}{x^2+(y-1)^2}=\cdots
$$

Comment: Should it be $x^2+(y-1)^2$ on the bottom of your last fraction rather than $x^2+(y+1)^2$?

Comment: @john.smith, righ, edited. Thanks.

Comment: Also is there a less trivial answer for the first part that is in terms of $z$ and the complex conjugate of $z$?

Comment: @john.smith, $\Re$ and $\Im$ can be disguised using that $z+\bar z=2\Re z$, $z-\bar z=\cdots$

Comment: @john.smith. more interesting question: under what conditions a polynomial $p(x,y)\in\Bbb C[x,y]$ can be written as $P(z)\in\Bbb C[z]$?